# IndentationError: unexpected indent while web scraping using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, indentation

I want to get the id number of the each match and save it in a text file?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://vip.win007.com/history/Odds_big.aspx?date=2020-8-1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

container0 = soup.find_all("odds", {"match": "id"})
print container0

with open('c:/logs/kellyrate.txt','a') as kellyrate:
kellyrate.write(container0 + "\n")
```

After run the script:

```
>>>IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Comment: indent `kellyrate.write` inside the `with`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

...implies that there were indentation errors in your code block.

---

### Python Indentation

[Indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp#:%7E:text=Indentation%20refers%20to%20the%20spaces,indicate%20a%20block%20of%20code.) refers to the spaces at the beginning of a code line. Python uses indentation to indicate a block of code.

---

### This usecase

In your program, the line of code:

```
kellyrate.write(container0 + "\n")
```

acts as a block of code which will be iterated for each line in `c:/logs/kellyrate.txt`. So you need to **indent** this line of code either by:

- *tab* character
- *blank space* characters

So your effective code block will be:

```
with open('c:/logs/kellyrate.txt','a') as kellyrate:
    kellyrate.write(container0 + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you must properly indent statements after ':'.
Change

```
with open('c:/logs/kellyrate.txt','a') as kellyrate:
kellyrate.write(container0 + "\n")
```

to

```
with open('c:/logs/kellyrate.txt','a') as kellyrate:
    kellyrate.write(container0 + "\n")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Alau\.spyder-py3\001.py", line 13, in <module>
    kellyrate.write(container0 + "\n")

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: After copied the above answer to my script, the other Error shown. But the main problem is that the "match id" cannot be print out.

Comment: This is because `find_all` returns  a list of items it found. You need to convert it to a string. For example by joining the list with `.join()`